# Is there a standard model/pattern for building web sites for Azure IoT Hub/Suite implementations?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

I see that the Azure IoT Suite [mentions Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-suite-overview/), but I can't seem to find any documentation or source which might explain/implement a web app.

Is there a standard pattern for developing a web-based application (e.g., Core MVC App) around the Azure IoT resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "standard pattern" however if you're looking for a head start, the source code for both Azure IoT Suite solutions ([Predictive Maintenance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-predictive-maintenance) and [Remote Monitoring](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring)) is available on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty obvious - I just didn't realize that these examples contained web apps, but the View model for both definitely includes  cshtml.